# Tab-bar-item pixelated (iOS 7.1)

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

My problem is that I have 2 tab bar items. 
The left is very sharp. But the right is pixelated.

Here's an screenshot:

[image]

Hope you can help me.

Comment: The right one is using a custom image. Did you provide two variants (normal and `@2x`) at the correct sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have a retina image specified for the pixelated graphic.